# ERROR : create a file in c disk by cmd in windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10-desktop

When i write **`nul.>`** on `cmd` I get:

> Access is denied.

How can I make a file on the C drive?  I tried to use the **`echo.>`** command but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the beginning open the command prompt "Run as administrator" and press enter for each line..

1. cd\
2. type nul > hellofile.txt
3. echo.>hellofile.txt

Comment: why when i type nul.>  (Access is denied.) appear but it create the file?

Answer (score 0):

The root of the system drive has restricted access, requiring elevated permissions to write to it. The same is true of some subfolders.

To create a file on the C drive therefore, you should create it in a subfolder to which you have access.